# Content Observer with Files?

Tags: android, file, contentobserver

So my Question is to know if ContentObserver can be used to Monitor a Folder and get Notified when a file is Created/Removed ?

in my Case , i want to Monitor the Camera Folder and get Notified when a new file is Created (Picture Taken) ,

Thanks .

Comment: There is a [`FileObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) that you could try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my Question is to know if ContentObserver can be used to Monitor a Folder and get Notified when a file is Created/Removed ?

No.

> in my Case , i want to Monitor the Camera Folder and get Notified when a new file is Created (Picture Taken)

You can either use a `ContentObserver` with `MediaStore` to find out when any images are added or removed, or you can use `FileObserver` to monitor the standard path to pictures on external storage.

Neither of these will necessarily reflect "Picture Taken", as camera apps do not have to store their images in that specific folder, nor do they have to have their images indexed by `MediaStore`.

Comment: No CommonsWare iam Not Talking on you , i know you are a very Good Developper (Expert) & i Respect you for this , you Help peoples with 'Pleasure' and Thanks you , but iam Talking about Somes peoples Voting down for no any Good reason , also , Automatic Filter doesnt play in my Favor ...

Comment: Also , iam learning 80% by Reading Stack Overflow and 20% Asking Questions

Comment: I Wanted to Ask a Question ... is there any ways i can Contact  you for Help CommonsWare ? , When i need it and when you have Free Time/and Accept it ...